# Uploading .heic images in Rails 3.2 using paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heic

Users are unable to upload .heic images.  Doesn't seem to be as simple as adding "images/heic" to content_type validations or just changing the file type to .jpg or .png.  Is there a way to get this done using paperclip or should we use an API to convert the .heic image to .jpg or .png before attaching and uploading?